# How to inspect or save large matrix to file in Spark

Tags: python, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, bigdata

I have created a large Block Matrix in PySpark called mtm with 85K x 85K dimensions.  I would like to inspect the Matrix to make sure it is created the way I wanted.  I have tried different routes and all of them failed with memory issues with Exit code 143 or 92.

Options that I have tried so far:
1. to convert the matrix to rdd and take a look at the first entry:

```
mtm_coor = mtm.toCoordinateMatrix()
mtm_rdd = mtm_coor.entries
mtm_rdd.take(1)
```

2. Save it to a text file

   mtm_rdd.saveAsTextFile('./mtm.txt')
3. Convert it to a DataFrame

   mtm_df = mtm_rdd.toDF()

My question is to figure out a workflow in PySpark.  How do I inspect a large matrix without running out of memory and how to save a large matrix to file without running into memory issues?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that when executing 'save to text file' or '.take(5)', the previous defined operations will all run at this step.  The OOM error means the operation is too large to fit in the memory.  The only solution is to look for more efficient operations.